# Angular group by ng-repeat filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using this library :
https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby

So I can group list items, but my problem is a little different,

Suppose that this is my data set:

```
[
    {name: 'foo', date: '2015-01-01'},
    {name: 'bar', date: '2015-01-04'},
    {name: 'bazz', date: '2015-02-22'},
    {name: 'ahh', date: '2015-06-15'},
    {name: 'qwe', date: '2015-06-16'},
]
```

I want to filter it by month, and year and the library doesn't suffice what I need.

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in items | groupBy: 'date'">
    <h1><--MONTH--></h1>
    <p>{{value.details}}</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can convert the date string into date parts like day, month and year and then pass the nested property to `groupBy` filter.

Convert data to this.

```
[
    {name: 'foo', date: {day: 1, month: 'January', year: 2015 }
    {name: 'foo', date: {day: 1, month: 'February', year: 2015 }
    ..
    ..
]
```

You can convert the date string into date parts using the below logic

```
var data = [....]
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];
angular.forEach(data, function (d) {
  d.date = new Date(d.date);
  d.date = {
    d: dt.getDate(),
    m: monthNames[d.date.getMonth()],
    y: d.date.getFullYear() 
  };
})
```

Html

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in items | groupBy: 'date.month'">
    <h1><--MONTH--></h1>
    <p>{{value.details}}</p>
</li>
```